# Programming by Assumption VS. What

Tags: design-patterns

When we approach a project in a top-down fashion, we often call it programming by assumption.

What should we call it when we create the building blocks first, and then proceed to build our project?

EDIT:

I'm looking for the bottom-up counterpart of `programming by assumption`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should call it bottom-up programming.

Comment: Is there a more idiomatic way of saying it?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng -- Are you specifically looking for the counterpart of `programming by assumption`?

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng -- making that explicit in the question might help you get better answers.

Comment: How? Could you please edit the question for me?